# How to configurate sqlite in wampserver 2.5

Tags: java

i have wampserver 2.5 in my machine.i want to use sqlite. i create a .php file and after i run that gave a error like this:Fatal error: Call to undefind function sqlite_open().Please enyone help me.

Comment: enable extension=php_sqlite in php.ini file

Comment: Please Tamil explain me where is locate php.ini.i can't find it.

Comment: Tamil i found that file and enabled extension=php_sqlite.But is giving same error.Please you can give me an advice

Answer (score 0):

sqlite_open() is a function of sqlite2 or less

in wampserver 2.5 only work sqlite3

check the documentation of sqlite in 
http://php.net/manual/en/class.sqlite3.php